High-speed counter for Arduino
I need to count electronic pulses that last around 3 ns with an amplitude of 1 V. They arrive at random times, with usually a separation of more than 100 ns.
The counted signal should not have a high precision (1-10%) and should be sensitive in the region of around 100 kHz (if it is lower it should return a small number, even if not accurate, and if it is high it should return a high count rate even not accurate)
 An Arduino Board should read the count-rate should every 100 \$\mu\$s.
Arduino cannot directly read this signal as its clock is too slow, therefore I require an external counting circuit. I am already capable of measuring the count rate with other devices but I require a low-cost solution (<100 $) that can easily and quickly interact with Arduino.
Moreover, the input signal should see a low impedance (50 Ohm)
I have two paths:
use an integrating op-amp circuit and read the output every 100 \$\mu\$s with the function AnalogRead and reset the condenser with a transistor in parallel to the condenser.
From the output signal I will have to calibrate the counts (which is easy)
This solution is straightforward but  I need a high-bandwidth amplifier.
-what is the limiting factor caused by the speed of the pulse for the integrator? the tau constant or the bandwidth of the amplifier?
-should I use high-speed comparators to obtain a longer pulse?

moreover, the circuit should be able to get a sufficiently high output (tau should be small)

-use a digital counter, but require a more complex electronics and it should communicate quickly with Arduino.
what solution and what electronic components do you suggest?

It sounds as though whatever (unspecified) thing is generating your pulse, it's designed well. For narrow pulses like that, a 1 V peak into 50 Ohm termination is almost a standard. Can you provide the spec sheet for your source? (If custom, there should still be written specs, I imagine. You've already mentioned one -- 50 Ohms.) Regardless, why not consider a simple counter that is latched to a register you can read once every 100 us? (Reset the counter, of course, to start each period.) Seems simple. AUC family can have Vcc=1.2 V and is very fast. (Tolerates 3.6 V at input.) AUP another opt.

I have used a microcontroller's built-in counter to measure accurately input frequencies up over 100 MHz. While not specified by the manufacturer, its 8-bit prescaler is asynchronous - allowing it to increment very fast. While prescaler count value is not directly readable, adding an input NAND gate and using software, its value can be captured. I believe some Microchip's AVR and PIC counter modules can do this. I used PIC16F684. A simple pulse-count solution, but likely still requires some interface buffer circuit.

Thank you for your comments!
I will try and look more into the AUC family and PIC counters
The signal is the output of a single photon detector.
